# Undefined variable error in node.tpl.php

Tags: nodes

I'm having an issue with an undefined variable

> Notice: Undefined variable: comment_count in include() (line 33 of ...\themes\simplecorp\node.tpl.php).

This is what my line 33 looks like:

```
<?php print $comment_count; ?>
```

I don't understand this error, Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: this error would occur for a node that doesn't have a comment count, as the variable won't have been set. T-34's answer should work to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rid of this notice, replace your line 33 with:

```
<?php if (isset($comment_count)) print $comment_count; ?>
```